# Using the package Chessboard, as mark with the + sign a square on a chessboard?

Tags: chessboard

I can mark a square with X or with a circle, but I still can't to mark with the + sign.
[image]

```
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\newchessgame

\chessboard[maxfield=c4, color=black,
markstyle=cross,markfields=a2,
markstyle=cross,markfields=a3,
markstyle=cross,markfields=b1,
markstyle=cross,markfields=b2,
markstyle=cross,markfields=b3,
markstyle=cross,markfields=b4,
markstyle=cross,markfields=c2,
markstyle=cross,markfields=c3, 
pgfstyle={[fill]circle},
markarea=\mycenter,
padding=-0.8ex,color=black,
markfields=a1,
markfields=a4,
markfields=c1,
markfields=c4, showmover=false]

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You get use the text mark type and insert a real plus. Or you will have to define a suitable markstyle.

Comment: Chris H- Excuse me, I've tried replacing the line markstyle=cross,markfields=a2, for markstyle=+,markfields=a2, but does not work.
How can I do

Comment: Ulrike Fischer- Please, How I to define a suitable markstyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a plus style e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\makeatletter
\cbDefinePgfFieldStyle{plus}{%
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \setlength\len@board@tempx{\dimexpr 0.1em + \board@pgf@shortenstart \relax}%
    \pgfsetshortenstart{\len@board@tempx}%
    \setlength\len@board@tempx{\dimexpr 0.1em + \board@pgf@shortenend \relax}%
    \pgfsetshortenend{\len@board@tempx}%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\board@pgf@linewidth}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{0}{0.5}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxy{0}{-0.5}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{-0.5}{0}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxy{0.5}{0}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\chessboard[maxfield=c4, color=black,
markstyle=plus,markfields=c3]

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike Fischer- Thanks. Works. Unfortunately, after reading the Chessboard, couldn't find the solution. Thanks.